# Como almacenar diferentes tipos de datos en un array (java)

Tags: java

Buenas noches tengo un problema he creado una tabla, lo cual quiero añadirle un evento que al hacer clic me guarde datos de diferentes tipos ya sea `double`, `Object` e `integer`.

```
            int numCols = table.getModel().getColumnCount();
            Object [] fila = new Object [numCols]; 

             fila[0] = txtcodigo.getText();
             fila[1] = txtnombre.getText();
             fila[2] = txtmarca.getText();
             fila [4] = txtprecio.getText(); // aquí es donde quiero guardar 
                                             // datos tipo double
```

Comment: Hola Husiel, bienvenido! Fíjate que estás declarando el objeto fila como un array de objects, pero lo estás inicializando como array de strings, así que solo va a recibir strings, decláralo e inicialízalo como array de objects así: object[] fila = new object[]; y entonces podrá recibir cualquier tipo de dato pues todos heredan de object.

Comment: Pero al realizar una operacion de multiplicacion o suma con un tipo de dato object no se puede como haria,? mi fin es que esos datos los pueda llegar a usar en otras tablas para poder hallar un total o multiplicar por alguna cantidad. Espero dejarme entender Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que tienes un arreglo de objetos, perfectamente puedes almacenar `Double`'s en este:

Tomando como ejemplo tu código, vamos a valernos del método estático `valueOf` de la clase `Double`, que acepta un string como parámetro, lo interpreta y nos devuelve una instancia de la clase con el número que representa, quedaría algo como:

```
fila[4] = Double.valueOf(txtprecio.getText());
```

Comment: Pero al realizar una operacion de multiplicacion o suma con un tipo de dato object no se puede, como haria,? Con el valueOf me retorna los datos en Double? Gracias por la ayuda !

Comment: Esa es una nueva pregunta. Tu pregunta era como almacenar el dato. En mi opinión eso ya está respondido. Si tienes una nueva pregunta, te invito a utilizar de nuevo el botón "Formular una pregunta", para pedir ayuda a la comunidad. Por el momento, el `Double` ya está en el arreglo.

Comment: Esta bien gracias, me ha servido de mucho.

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha servido, puedes marcarla como aceptada (si no sabes como, te invito a hacer el [tour]). Esto sirve para que personas que en el futuro encuentren esto como parte de su investigación sepan que hubo una respuesta que le sirvió al quien publicó la pregunta para resolver su duda o problema. Un saludo.

Comment: Solo como comentario, para resolver lo de la multiplicación, puedes utilizar un molde de tipo. Ya que sabes que la posición 4 es un double, puedes indicarle a java que conoces eso con la sintaxis `(Double)`, por ejemplo `Double resultado = (Double)fila[4] * 2:`

Comment: Gracias amigo me sirve mucho esto !!